# Sum #'s extracted from text string

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have a formulated column 'Adjs Amount' in an excel table that extracts an amount from a text sting in another column: =IF(W598="YES",((MID(S598,FIND("CO-237",S598)+8,3))),0).

But When I try to sum the Adjs Amount Column it doesn't recognize the extracted numbers and gives me zero.
`
Does anyone know a way around this?

TABLE SCREEN SHOT:

Comment: The screenshot isn't showing and the code isn't properly formatted. Oh, and make sure you add the tag for the language you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Does save the answer as a text? Maybe try to put the INT formula around it.

Answer (score 0):

I Figured it out:

=NUMBERVALUE(IF(W598="YES", ((MID(S598,FIND("CO-237",S598)+8,4))),0))